# Parse JSON in Mule 3.2 Flow

Tags: json, expression, esb, mule, jsonpath

If I have the following JSON

```
[ 
  { "category": "reference",
    "author": "Nigel Rees",
    "title": "Sayings of the Century",
    "price": 8.95
  },
  { "category": "fiction",
    "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
    "title": "Sword of Honour",
    "price": 12.99
  },
  { "category": "fiction",
    "author": "Herman Melville",
    "title": "Moby Dick",
    "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
    "price": 8.99
  },
  { "category": "fiction",
    "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
    "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
    "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
    "price": 22.99
  }
]
```

I can get the price of "Moby Dick" using the following JSONPath:

```
$..[?(@.title=='Moby Dick')].price
```

RESULT:

```
'0' => "8.99"
```

BUT how do I do this in Mule..... what would the json expression look like to get the same result within a mule 3.2 flow?

I don't mind if your answer shows how to do it another way as long as I get the same result within mule.

Can anyone please help me with this??

Comment: would something like this be possible    #[json-node://[title=='Moby Dick']/price]

Answer (score 3):

The way to do that with MEL is to deserialize the JSON payload and use an [MVEL filtered projection](http://mvel.codehaus.org/MVEL+2.0+Projections+and+Folds):

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.List" />
<expression-transformer 
    expression="#[($.price in message.payload if $.title == 'Moby Dick')[0]]" />
```

This expression doesn't take into account cases when `Moby Dick` isn't present. You didn't mention what to do in that case: I can beef up the expression if you specify the desired behavior when the book's not found.

Comment: I do agree with David. Mule's [JSONPath](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mule.modules/mule-module-json/3.1.0/org/mule/module/json/JsonExpressionEvaluator.java) support it's pretty basic and definitely not what you are expecting.

Comment: This isn't working for me in mule 3.2.   I am getting this error message:   expression-transformer must have all attributes for one of the sets: [evaluator, expression].

Comment: Sorry, this is for 3.3. You should really upgrade: 3.2 is old many bugs have been killed in 3.3.

Comment: how easy is it to upgrade a production system to 3.3 and is it backward compatible? This could cause a big problem for me.

Comment: They should be backward compatible, especially if you use /current/ and not /3.2/ in your Mule namespaces (recommended). I've moved all my code from 3.2 to 3.3 without a hitch and never looked back :P

Comment: I have been wanting to do this for a while so I will investigate over Christmas. The Foreach message processor would make my life a lot easier! Thanks David.