# MULE ESB : Expression Filter with regex() function

Tags: java, regex, json, mule, esb

I'm having as payload some Json data like :

```
{
    "name" : "Italy"
}
```

I want to filter with a regex the content of my field "name".

By now I user this filter. There's no real error but it doesn't match.

```
<expression-filter expression="regex('^[a-zA-Z]{3,15}$' , 'json:name')" doc:name="Expression"/>
```

As a proof of using this regex() function if I put `'(.*)'` as regex pattern, it works.

```
<expression-filter expression="regex('(.*)' , 'json:name')" doc:name="Expression"/>
```

The documentation is [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Tips).

Someone understands my mistake?

[EDIT]

Then Matthew's solution works like that :

```
    <set-variable variableName="PayloadBackup" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Variable"/><json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.Map" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
    <expression-transformer expression="#[payload['name'].matches('^[a-zA-Z]{3,15}$')]" doc:name="Expression"/>
    <expression-filter expression="#[payload]" doc:name="Expression"/>
    <set-payload value="#[PayloadBackup]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```

It's ugly though.

If the string doesn't match the regex, the engine answer :

```
null (java.lang.NullPointerException). Message payload is of type: Boolean
```

I'm not able to catch this Excetion yet.

Thanks

Comment: After many tries, it seems impossible de deserialize json as string to java.lan.Object or java.util.List or any kind of collection. hence it's not possible to use filter injection when you deserialize Json in this situation.  If anyone has an idea I'm interested !

Answer (score 1):

see the section on [JSON processing](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Tips#MuleExpressionLanguageTips-JSONProcessing) or take a look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878830/parse-json-in-mule-3-2-flow)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if your regex expression is correct, but if it is you can always use the following code :-

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>

 <flow name="teFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-payload value="{&quot;name&quot; : &quot;Italy&quot;}" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
         <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
         <expression-filter expression="#[message.payload.name.matches('^[a-zA-Z]{3,15}$')]" doc:name="Expression"/>
         <logger level="INFO" message="message paased !!" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    </flow>
```

It will work as you expect :)

Answer (score 0):

Return false if matches error:

```
#[?payload['name'].matches('^[a-zA-Z]{3,15}$') or false]
```